# Oracle. If record exists by the first statement, ignore second one

Tags: sql, oracle, function, procedure

I'm having a question how to resolve my problem.

I have procedure where inside i'm having this `SELECT` inside `LEFT OUTER JOIN` witch are returning me some values:

```
SELECT * FROM database1 data1
                        JOIN database2 data2 ON data2.id = data1.attr_id
                        JOIN database3 data3 ON data3.attr_id = data2.id
                        JOIN database4 data4 ON data4.objt_attr_id = data3.id
                        JOIN database5 data5 ON data5.stya_id = data4.id
                            AND data5.value = 1
        JOIN database6 data6 ON data6.id = data5.sero_id
        JOIN database7 data7 ON srv.id = data6.srv_id
        JOIN database8 data8 ON data8.code IN ('CALC1','CALC2')
        WHERE data1.ordet_id IN (data8.id)
```

As you can see he is looking for `CALC1` and `CALC2` And then search by their `ID's` in `data1.ordet_id`.
Naturally, he return me 2 entries witch is not correct.

How to make the check. When script will find record with `CALC1`, then he skips the check on `CALC2`, so the script is returning only 1 record by `CALC1`(not like now for both). And vice versa, if by `CALC1` record wasn't found, he check the `CALC2`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take advantage of the analytical function `row_number` as following:

```
select * from
(SELECT data1.*, data2.*, .. data8.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by data1.ordet_id order by data8.code ) as rn 
        FROM database1 data1
        JOIN database2 data2 ON data2.id = data1.attr_id
        JOIN database3 data3 ON data3.attr_id = data2.id
        JOIN database4 data4 ON data4.objt_attr_id = data3.id
        JOIN database5 data5 ON data5.stya_id = data4.id
                            AND data5.value = 1
        JOIN database6 data6 ON data6.id = data5.sero_id
        JOIN database7 data7 ON srv.id = data6.srv_id
        JOIN database8 data8 ON data8.code IN ('CALC1','CALC2')
        WHERE data1.ordet_id IN (data8.id))
where rn = 1
```

**-- Update**

As per your below comment, You can also use `NOT EXISTS` and combination of `CASE..WHEN` as following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM
    DATABASE1 DATA1
    JOIN DATABASE2 DATA2 ON DATA2.ID = DATA1.ATTR_ID
    JOIN DATABASE3 DATA3 ON DATA3.ATTR_ID = DATA2.ID
    JOIN DATABASE4 DATA4 ON DATA4.OBJT_ATTR_ID = DATA3.ID
    JOIN DATABASE5 DATA5 ON DATA5.STYA_ID = DATA4.ID
                            AND DATA5.VALUE = 1
    JOIN DATABASE6 DATA6 ON DATA6.ID = DATA5.SERO_ID
    JOIN DATABASE7 DATA7 ON SRV.ID = DATA6.SRV_ID
    JOIN DATABASE8 DATA8 ON DATA8.CODE IN (
        'CALC1',
        'CALC2'
    )
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN DATA8.CODE = 'CALC1' THEN DATA1.ORDET_ID
        WHEN DATA8.CODE = 'CALC2' THEN CASE
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM
                    DATABASE8 D8
                WHERE DATA1.ORDET_ID = D8.ID
                  AND D8.CODE = 'CALC1'
            ) THEN DATA1.ORDET_ID
        END
    END = DATA8.ID
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you! But here is the problem, he will still return 2 entries, but with `rown_number` he will just hide the second, witch is not OK, because he should check if record with `CALC1` exists, if not, he takes a look on `CALC2`.

Answer (score 1):

Join twice with `OUTER JOIN` (i.e. you loose no record if the matched code doesn't exists, but **you will not duplicate the result**) and the get the priorized code with `COALESCE` from the first or second join.

```
SELECT 
   data1.ordet_id ,
   COALESCE(data81.code, data82.code) code
FROM data1.ordet_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN data81 ON data1.ordet_id = data81.id and data81.code = 'CALC1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN data82 ON data1.ordet_id = data82.id and data82.code = 'CALC2'
```